# Exclude category from author posts list in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops, posts, author

I am looking for a way to exclude a category from an author page. I have a category written by one author however when you navigate to the author archive page, I want that category to not show up while displaying all other post by that author.

Here is how the code is that makes up my custom author page

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="mh-wrapper clearfix">
    <div id="main-content" class="mh-content">

    <?php
        mh_before_page_content();
        mh_magazine_lite_page_title();
        ?>

    <p><img style="border-bottom:3px solid black;" src="http://chaseonair.com/wp-content/themes/theme-andrews/images/chase-blog-header.jpg"></p>

    <?php
        if (category_description()) { ?>

        <?php
        }
        if (is_author()) {
            mh_magazine_lite_author_box();
        }
        if (have_posts()) {
            while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                get_template_part('content', 'loop');
            endwhile;
            mh_magazine_lite_pagination();
        } else {
            get_template_part('content', 'none');
        } ?>
    </div>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have looked online and found this

```
query_posts($query_string . "&cat=-1");
```

I have tried using this however it either results in an error or when I navigate to older posts it only displays the first 5 post again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the pre_get_posts filter to achive this:

```
<?php
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_from_author_pages' );

    function exclude_category_from_author_pages( $query ) {
        if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_author('jack') ) {
            $query->set( 'cat', '-4' );
        }
        else if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_author('john') ) { 
            $query->set( 'cat', '-5' );
        }
        else if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_author('steve') ) {  
            $query->set( 'cat', '-7' );
        }   
    }
?>
```

Note that you can also use `$query->is_author(8)` where 8 is the userid of the user with nickname 'john'

Comment: This is not working for me. Where exactly should I place this code?

Comment: Put it at the bottom of the functions.php of your theme. Just don't forget to replace '4' with the ID of the actual category that you need to exclude.

Comment: Here is that problem with that. I have one author that writers posts in category A and B. I want to exclude that category B from their author archive page. Then I have another author that writes posts for categories C, D, E & F and I need to exclude category E from this author as well. Is there a code I can use right on the custom author archive page that I have created? I would like to be able to control the exclusion of categories for each individual author.

Comment: I have placed this code in the top of my functions page but it seems to have no effect. The category I am trying to hide is still there.

Comment: I placed the code in the top of my functions.php file. I have taken it out for now. The code for my functions page is at http://chaseonair.com/html-pages/functions.txt. I did replace the -4 with the my own category and jack with my the author id but had no luck. I also did this for the other authors and categories.

Comment: Try putting the code at the bottom, because there is a possibility that some other code in one of the files being included (mh-custom-functions.php, for example) could be overriding your code.

Also put this line  `echo 'I am in exclude_category_from_author_pages';` in the function , so that we know that function is even being called or not.

Comment: I placed the code at the bottom of the functions page but still am not getting the category to not show. I have updated the functions page at http://chaseonair.com/html-pages/functions.txt. When I added the echo in it did display at the top of the page.

Comment: Okay, that is progress. We know the function is being hit. Now can you put some different echo statements in the different echo clauses. Probably some code like:
`echo 'I am in first if';` and then `echo 'I am in second if';`

If neither of these echo statements get displayed, then try adding this at the beginning of the the function:
`var_dump($query);` and paste the output here

Comment: where should I place the echo statements in the code? I just moved it around when I tested it the first time. Also, thank you for your help.

Comment: I placed the echo statement after `$query->set( 'cat', '-6' );` for both lines. It gave me nothing. I added the other code and it said null

Comment: `var_dump($query);` gives you null? That is very strange!
Can you double-check that the `var_dump($query);` line is the first line in your function `exclude_category_from_author_pages` ?

Comment: I have uploaded the new code to the txt file. This code caused null to show up at the top of the page. I have also noticed that the header image I have added into the custom author page disappears. Could I have something in the author page incorrect? The code for the custom author page is in the original post.

Comment: I don't see any `echo` or `var_dump` statements in the code. This is where I am looking at: http://chaseonair.com/html-pages/functions.txt

Comment: I must not have uploaded the right code. Did you also refresh the page? I had to do this to see the update. I am not sure where to put the echo statements in the code.

Comment: Correct your code to this:
`add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_from_author_pages' );
function exclude_category_from_author_pages( $query ) {
 var_dump($query);
 echo "<br> I am in exclude_category_from_author_pages";
 if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_author('6') ) {
  echo "<br> I am in first if";
  $query->set( 'cat', '-385' );
 }
 else if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_author('9') ) {
  echo "<br> I am in second if";
  $query->set( 'cat', '-1' );
 }  
}`

Comment: I have changed the code at chaseonair.com/html-pages/functions.txt. This is what I got at the top of the page when I uploaded the code to my functions page. NULL & I am in exclude_category_from_author_pages.

Comment: Your code is wrong. From what I see var_dump($query) is outside the function `exclude_category_from_author_pages`
This wont work. You have to put it INSIDE the function.

Just put the code I pasted above, otherwise we can't proceed further.

Comment: Here is the code again for your reference:
`/***** Author Category Exclusion *****/

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_from_author_pages' );

 
function exclude_category_from_author_pages( $query ) { 
 echo "<br> I am in exclude_category_from_author_pages";
 var_dump($query);
 if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_author('6') ) {
  echo "<br> I am in first if";
  $query->set( 'cat', '-385' );
 }
 else if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_author('9') ) { 
  echo "<br> I am in second if"; 
  $query->set( 'cat', '-1' );
 }  
}`

Comment: Updated code is up. It cause the site to error out. I had a bunch of code at the top and also in different parts of page.

Comment: What error does it cause?
What messages did you see printed on the page? 
Can you post them here?

Comment: The error message is too long to post here so I have uploaded it here. http://chaseonair.com/html-pages/error.txt. Do I have the correct code in the functions page?

Comment: The output you see is'nt error. Its the debug output.
The code you have written is correct.
Now the question comes whether you are trying to view the correct page?
I ask this because the output shows the is_author parameter to be false, which SHOULD NOT happen if it is an author archive page. 

2 VERY IMPORTANT questions:
a) What is the link of the the page you are trying to view. Does not matter if it is on local machine, I just need to see the url structure.

b) If and only if you have written your custom author archive template, then please post the filename of the template here.

Comment: I have written a custom author page. The file structure is http://chaseonair.com/author/chase. The file uploaded to the server is named author-6.php. The code that is used is in the very first post. The page that I got the message on was the home page http://chaseonair.com. I have not tried this in any other page.

Comment: I added the code back to my functions page and pulled the output from the author page. The updated code it at http://chaseonair.com/html-pages/error.txt

Comment: I am pretty sure, you are doing something wrong. Because the error you posted shows is_author = false and on the same time it shows is_category=true. It also shows is_archive = true. Which means it is anarchive page..but NOT author archive page, rather it is category archive page error output

Comment: For making it easier to get debug information, can you install the "debug bar" plugins? See the screenshot here:http://prnt.sc/cf44zy

Once these plugins are activated, open the author archive page and on the admin bar click on Debug->WP Query as shown in the screenshot at http://prnt.sc/cf446c

Also if possible, can you try to let the debug code in place on the website so that I can check it from here? If the website already has traffic, then obviously you wont want to do this

Comment: I don't want to leave the debug information on the site as this is a live site. Did you look at the code I have used to make up my author archive page? Is there something wrong in that code? Would it be easier for me to create custom category pages and just add the author box to that page for the author I want to show?

Comment: 1. Your code for author archive page looks fine. Just one thing, you've got `get_header();` twice.

2 Are you sure the author id of the user **chase** is **6** ?

3. Can you try renaming author-6.php to author.php ?

4. Did you install the "debug bar" plugins I mentioned in my previous post?

Comment: **5.** Also put the given code in your function's php:
`/**** Author Category Exclusion ****/
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category_from_author_pages' );

function exclude_category_from_author_pages( $query ) {
 echo "<div style='display:none;'>";
 var_dump($query);
 echo "</div>";
 if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_author('6') ) {
  echo "<div style='display:none;'>";
  echo "In if";
  echo "</div>";
  $query->set( 'cat', '-385' ); 
 } 
 else { 
  echo "<div style='display:none;'>";
  echo "In else";
  echo "</div>";
  $query->set( 'cat', '-1' ); 
 } 
}`

Comment: **6.** The above code WILL print the debug BUT it will NOT be visible to ANYONE except those who know